# How to properly view a .sqlite file using sqlite?

Tags: file-format, sqlite, sqlite3

I have installed the program `sqlite` in order to view file types with that extension, however even after reading its help documentation and its manpage, I am still confused about how I get it to show me what I want. So how exactly do you use this program? I just want to properly view a file of that extension.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Comment: What output or view type do you want? There are also GUI database explorers which would be easier to handle, I think.

Comment: @ByteCommander: Depends what types there are, could you give me some examples? Also, I don't really mind if it is in CLI or GUI.

Comment: BTW are you sure you want `sqlite` and not `sqlite3`?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: I don't know... All I know is I have `.sqlite` files created by Firefox that I want to view.

Comment: `sqlite` is the old version. I strongly suggest you use `sqlite3` but you probably already did that if you installed the wonderful `sqlitebrowser` as suggested in the A. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: Well, I attempted at first (before asking this question) to use `sqlite` but that didn't get anywhere. I have now purged that and installed `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Let's start with the more user-friendly way and use the GUI tool `sqlitebrowser`. It offers you to easily explore a database without having to know SQL commands.

You can install it with the command

```
sudo apt install sqlitebrowser
```

and run it from the launcher/dash/application menu or using the command

```
sqlitebrowser
```

In the main window you can click <kbd>Open database</kbd> to open your `*.sqlite` file. It will then display something like this (here displaying the database of a Firefox add-on for applying user styles):

[image]

I already switched to the <kbd>Browse Data</kbd> tab on the left panel, where you can view the database table contents now. You select which table to display in the "Table:" combobox.

---

Of course you can also do this from the command-line, using e.g. `sqlite3`. This method requires you to know at least a basic set of SQL commands and is better suited for advanced users or if you need to parse the output in a script.

You install `sqlite3` using the command

```
sudo apt install sqlite3
```

and then run it with the following command (`-column` and `-header` option for better readability of the output, see `man sqlite3` for more info):

```
sqlite3 -column -header
```

Then you get an interactive SQLite3 command prompt, like this:

```
$ sqlite3 -column -header
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite>
```

The first thing you must do now is to open the database file. Therefore you can use the `.open` SQLite command. Enter this to the `sqlite>` prompt (again using the same Firefox add-on database as above, you will type a different path of course):

```
.open "/home/bytecommander/.mozilla/firefox/gtltfeay.default/stylish.sqlite"
```

Note that <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion works here and will help you to enter the path to your database file.

You can now see the list of loaded databases using the `.databases` command (file name is truncated because it's so long):

```
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /home/bytecommander/.mozilla/firefox/gtltfeay.default/styl
```

You see the database we just opened is now called `main`.

In the next step we list all tables of the `main` (default) database:

```
sqlite> .tables
style_meta  styles
```

We see the two tables `style_meta` and `styles` listed.

Let's display the `style_meta` table completely with all columns. Therefore we need the SQL command `SELECT * FROM style_meta;` (don't forget the semicolon!):

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM style_meta;
id          style_id    name        value      
----------  ----------  ----------  -----------
46          1           domain      lichess.org
47          1           type        site       
48          3           domain      lichess.org
49          3           type        site       
50          2           domain      lichess.org
51          2           type        site       
53          4           type        global
```

To get help with commands specific to SQLite3's interactive shell (commands starting with a period), type `.help` at the `sqlite>` prompt or read its manpage `man sqlite3`. All other commands are common SQL, you should search for a basic SQL tutorial to learn them.

You can exit the interactive `sqlite3` shell again using the `.exit` command or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: I would suggest the `.schema` command to see how tables and fields were created.

Comment: Bad experience with sqlitebrowser. It hung when I ran a query or when the window was moved to background. Switched to command line tool after that.

Comment: Thank you @Byte Commander for such a beautiful and thorough answer.

Comment: `ctrl+d` is a "clean exit" in sqlite3 leaving no running process.